# Javascript/jQUERY not working on MVC 4 Visual Studio 2012 project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use jQuery to create a simple menu but it won't work. Most Javascript I use on my sites either don't work at all or throw errors.

For example, I can download the solution offered in the tutorial below and JavaScript will work from the downloaded files, but not from my own projects I create, even if they are 100% identical.

http://rjdudley.com/creating-a-simple-dynamic-menu-in-asp-net-mvc/

So again and for the website above: Even if I follow the tutorial, jQuery won't work while it works for the downloaded solution.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
                <nav>
                    @Html.Action("Menu", "Home")
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>
                    &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#menu").menu();
        });
    </script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should check your JavaScript console, I'd bet either JQuery isn't being downloaded succesfully, or there's a javascript error somewhere.

Comment: I edited to add some code but really it's the same as on thw website.

Comment: As @Shriike said, you need to check your Inspector. Either there is an error in the Console with some javascript you have on the page (that can prevent all other javascript/jquery from working) or the assets are just not properly loading. Try loading in the assets directly, instead of via Bundlr, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: What should I look for in the inspector? I can see some changes in the code when I hover over the menu, but it still looks different from the example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome or FireFox you should be able to "right click" and "inspect element". Then you should see an tab that says "Console". Any errors will show up there. If you get a "$" is undefined then jQuery is not loading.

You can see what files are loaded by then hitting the "Sources" tab (in Chrome something similar in FireFox). Expand each of the sources and see if jQuery is there. If not you have something missing.

I find it easiest to get jQuery working, by adding a `<script src="~/myjsfile.js"/>` directly to the layout page.

Hope this helps